# depending on select box value need to display view table in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have one view selection table in my application..in that i display all the view selection details..but what i want to do is i want to display the view selection depending on the role name..i have role_id in my selection table..i get the role names in dropdown..

this is my Controller:

```
public function  vendor_view_selection()
{
    $data['rolename']=$this->SelectionModel->getrolename();
    $data['view_selection'] = $this->SelectionModel->getselection();
    $this->load->view('selection/vendor_view_selection',$data);
}
```

This is my Model:

```
function getselection() 
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('selection');
    $this->db->join('role','role.role_id= selection.role_id');
    $this->db->join('candidates_details','candidates_details.candidate_id=selection.candidate_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

select box for role name:(depending on selected role name need to display selection details)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose  RoleName</label>
    <select  class="form-control"  multiple class="form-control" data-placeholder="Role name"  name="role_id" >
        <option value="0"></option>
        <?php foreach($rolename as $rows) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows->role_id?>"><?php echo ucfirst($rows->role_name)?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

**view:(view_selection)table**

```
<div class="box-body">
  <table id="" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>selection </th>
        <th>comments</th>
        <th>results</th>
        <th>candidate</th>
        <th>role</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
<?php 
foreach ($view_selection as $idata) { 
?>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="domain<?php echo $idata->selection_id;?>">
        <td><?php echo $idata->selection;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $idata->comments;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $idata->results;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $idata->candidate_id;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $idata->role_id;?></td>
      </tr>
<?php 
} 
?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.box -->
</div>
```

Please anyone help me how to do that..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You have to use `ajax` on `change` event of your drop down.

Comment: Fix your HTML before attempting to use any javascript on it.

Comment: i dont have that much of familiar using ajax..can you please explain how can we use ajax on my dropdown..

Comment: @RiggsFolly what errors i need to fix?

Comment: Well for starters, removing the `<tbody>` from inside the `foreach` loop would be a good start.

Comment: I dont understand your problem clearly.for ajax see here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: If you don't want to use javascript just put a submit button next to the dropdown, and encase both in a form, then when they select an item, click submit (with the form action back to the same method), then grab the data using `$this->input->post('your_id')` and send that to the model. As PHP is a server side language, it wont dynamically load the way you seem to think it will. It will take a page reload to acheive.. Unless you use javascript

Answer (score 0):

Send list id by $.ajax to the special function in controller.

Then
 echo $this->load->view('view_selection',array(),true);//return string of view

exit();

i hope so worked for you,